# In Xcode, how do you copy resources with folders to target

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

I have a iOS project with a folder/group structure like this:

[image]

Xcode copies `lesson.xml` to my bundle without the enclosing folders, so I need to load it like this:

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "lesson", withExtension: "xml")
```

But I'd like the folders in the bundle, so I can have multiple lesson.xml files and load them like this:

```
let url1 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Lessons/Hello/lesson",
                           withExtension: "xml")
let url2 = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Lessons/Foo/lesson",
                           withExtension: "xml")
```

How do you copy a folder structure to the bundle?

Comment: There's not an easy way to do it. You'd have to add separate Copy Files phases for each destination folder. And you don't have to include the extension in the `forResource` argument if you've specified it in the `withExtension`.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried it and that works. Also I'll edit the question to remove the duplicated extension.

Comment: There IS an easy way. Use folder references instead of mere groups as you are doing now.

Comment: Thanks, that works too. (Deleted my previous comment. I just need to drag the folder in, not use "add files" menu item.)

Comment: Basically they are identical. Just two ways of making a folder reference.